# Как в PyCharm работать с .CSS?

Tags: css, pycharm

Для курса по верстке решил использовать PyCharm.

И не понимаю, вот с html все круто, есть подсказки, отступы, горячие клавиши для комментирования кода, а с .CSS ничего этого нет, будто в блокноте пишу.

Почему так? Надо купить платную версию? Или можно что то поднастроить?

Comment: Посмотрите установленные плагины. Там должны быть `CSS` и `HTML Tools`. Но у меня PyCharm Professional. Если они только в этой версии, то поищите в Marketplace аналоги

Answer (score 0, accepted):

И действительно в "Professional" всё как надо.

Я активировал ключ, Community стал Professional'ом и о чудо работать с CSS стало сплошным удовольствием, подсветка подсказки и прочее появились сами по себе

Comment: Написали бы подробное объяснение решения своего вопроса, а не оставили комментарий.

Comment: @MoloF Куда ж тут еще подробнее, за прохождение курсов мне дали ключ на несколько месяцев я его активировал, Community стал Professional'ом и о чудо работать с CSS стало сплошным удовольствием, подсветка подсказки и прочее появились сами по себе

Comment: Вот таких подробностей и хотелось бы услышать, мол подсветка только в Pro версии, а чтобы её получить можно пройти курс <название курса> и активировать Professional версию IDE